# How to authorize python script for Accessing Google API's?

Tags: python, google-api

I'm running python script for automate Youtubte video upload, and it always asks for,

`Please visit this URL to authorize this application`

How can i authorize the script running on my local machine to allow access the Google API ?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to give authorization to the app prior to use. All of this information can be found in the developer.google.com docs on YT. https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the YouTube Data API does not support service account authentication which would allow for no user interaction.

What you can do is authorize your code once and store the refresh token, your code then should be able to use the stored refresh token to access the data whenever it needs to.

Notice how in the following code the credentials are stored in the .dat file for later use.

```
  storage = file.Storage('storage.dat')
  credentials = storage.get()
  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
  http = credentials.authorize(http=httplib2.Http())
```